# How do I solve Fatal Error [Pe035] in IAR?

Tags: iar, stm32f4discovery

I have saved STM firmware in C:/ and in IAR I go to options -> Preprocessor -> select folder and I select C:\STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.27.0\Drivers\CMSIS\Include and the I get this error:

```
Fatal Error[Pe035]: #error directive: "Please select first the target STM32F4xx device used in your application (in stm32f4xx.h file)"
```

**main.c**

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error message pretty much says what you should do: specify the target STM32F4xx device before including the file `stm32f4xx.h`. I will explain why and how.

**Why:**
As the name suggests, this is the common header file for the whole STM32F4 family. However, the devices in this family have (minor) differences, so for each specific target device, other things might be included. This is handled using a define. You can see this in the [source](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/3d6be4bd406f275728e0a321cc371c62a3100533/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include/stm32f4xx.h#L127). Depending on the defined target, the appropriate header file for that specific target is included as well.

**How:**
Since the stm32f4discovery uses an STM32F407 device, you should define `STM32F407xx`. (If you use a different microcontroller, use another define. See the source for the available/supported options.) You could do this in two different ways.

Method 1: define a preprocessor macro before the include statement.

```c
#define STM32F407xx
#include <stm32f4xx.h>

...
```

Method 2 (recommended): add the define in the toolchain settings, so the option `-DSTM32F407xx` is added to the compiler options.

**Note:** Do NOT edit the file `stm32f4xx.h`, since this is (usually) a system-wide library file. It is shared between all projects, so if you also want to compile something for a different STM32F4 device, you will get into problems. Besides, when you update the library, you will lose your changes and the original error returns.

Answer (score -3):

As it says in the error, "select first the target STM32F4xx device used in your application (in stm32f4xx.h file)".

Open stm32f4xx.h, there you will find various microcontroller names commented out. Uncomment "#define STM32F469" (or whatever your MCU is), save file. Done. It will hook up all the files specific to your MCU.